# Django server calls Google pay API refund

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I can't find an open API for Google Pay that I can interact with from my Django server to make automated refunds for my customers who have bought some items but want a refund.

I am investigating [Google Pay API](https://developers.google.com/pay/api), but I can't find an open API that I can interact with from my django server. What I need is to make an automated refund for my customer, who have bought an item but wants a refund.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after days of research I've [found out](https://developers.google.com/pay/refundable-one-time-payment-code-v2/payment-integrator-refundable-one-time-payment-code-api) that the [workflow](https://developers.google.com/pay/refundable-one-time-payment-code-v2/google-refundable-one-time-payment-code-api/Refund.Flow) is not like this:

```
User -> My server -> Google Pay -> User
```

It's actually like this

```
User -> Google Pay -> My server -> Google Pay -> User
```

That's what I needed to understand to not ask this naive question.